# How to define a global background color for my shinyMobile application?

Tags: css, r, shiny, background

The default background color of a shinyMobile application is a light grey (especially: gainsboro `#DCDCD`). I want to set it to blue (especially: Deep Koamaru `#162580`).

A picture of what my application looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zaDp.png

A picture of how I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EFbC.png

Here is a simplified version of my application's code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)

shinyApp(
    ui = f7Page(
        title = "My App",
        options = list(theme = "auto"),
        f7SingleLayout(
            navbar = f7Navbar(
                title = "App"
            ),
            f7SmartSelect(
                inputId = "needs",
                label = "What are you looking for?",
                choices = list("need1", "need2", "need3"),
                openIn = "popup",
                multiple = TRUE
            ),
            f7SocialCard(
                author = "Me", 
                date = "Today",
                "Description",
                footer = tagList(
                    f7Button(
                        color = "green",
                        outline = FALSE, 
                        fill = FALSE,
                        label = f7Icon("phone_fill", style = "font-size: 25px;"),
                        href = paste0("tel:", 000)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    server = function(session, input, output) {}
)
```

I want to set my background color to blue.

I have found the name of the file to modify in order to change the background color using the elements inspector. Its name is `shinyMobile.css`. I've try using `tags` in different instances of fluidPage. I couldn't find a solution.

Also, here is a note from the author:

> Custom skins shinyMobile has 3 skins:
>
> aurora for desktop apps ios and md for mobile apps It automatically
> detects if the app is running with android or iOS and accordingly
> adapt the layout. It is of course possible to apply the iOS skin on
> android and inversely, even though not recommended.
>
> shinyMobile also provides 2 themes, namely light and dark. While
> framework7 allows to apply dark or light theme not only at the global
> level but at the “widget level”, shinyMobile does not support that
> feature, to improve the overall consistency. Only panels can have a
> color independent of the global theme.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm super late to the party answering this, but I figured I'd provide an answer to anyone else looking. What you'll want to do is copy the shinyMobile.css file and save it to your app's "www" folder. If your app doesn't have one, make it and put the shinyMobile.css file in there. Within the file, you can edit the background-color code, found on line 22, to your desired color. Here's the code changing your background to the desired color in the new shinyMobile.css file:

```
.light .split-layout .page-content:not(.login-screen-content, .panel-content),
.light .single-layout .page-content:not(.login-screen-content, .panel-content),
.light .tab-layout .page-content:not(.login-screen-content, .panel-content),
.light div.messages {
  background-color: #162580;
}
```

To include this new file in your shiny app, right after you begin your first f7Page command, use the following command to have that css file pull in: `includeCSS("www/shinyMobile.css")`
I hope this helps whoever comes across it next!